# cxcore210d.dll missing

Tags: visual-c++, dll, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV in Visual C++ express edition 2008. I've installed OpenCV 2.1 and added necessary include and lib directories/files to my project dependencies. A system PATH is also present for "C:\OpenCV2.1\bin".

When i compile and run the example program to open an image, I get a runtime error saying cxcore210d.dll is missing. I checked the bin folder and its there. 
I've looked at similar posts here and on Google and they suggested turning off incremental linker. This didn't change results.

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to restart my PC. I'm guessing without a restart some variables are not registered correctly. :s but now this runs fine.

If anyone is working with OpenCV, so get in touch. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "d" stands for a debug build. You need to compile the OpenCV library with "debug" options set. Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this with Visual C++ express edition. I've tried it before...

Comment: its possible to do it Debug mode. I am currently in debug mode and it compiles with 0 errors and 0 warnings. This error occurs in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

why not you copy your dll into the folder and beside the application.

Comment: thats a temporary solution. Its not convenient if I need to create more projects.

Answer (score 0):

hey i just solve this problem. copy `cxcore210d.dll` and `highgui210d.lib` from your `bin` folder and paste it in `lib` folder and see the result...

Comment: this method worked fine for me. But everytime it has to be repeated